# How to change the Json editor colors in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, themes

I am using JSON files with the JSON Editor extension for VS Code and I need to format them, but when I use the JSON Editor View, I cannot see the information clearly:

[image]

I cannot see the name of the nodes clearly, how can I change it? All dark themes do not allow to see it well, only light themes allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `"vscode-json-editor.theme": "dark"` in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

This problem was [raised a long time ago](https://github.com/sunmorgus/vscode-json-editor/issues/1), and [a change was made which added that setting to address the problem](https://github.com/sunmorgus/vscode-json-editor/commit/0ef38e5a770a767f35407ce64d7f6f1c0b9ee2e5). Of course, it would be nicer if this other issue ticket was addressed so the user wouldn't need to manually do this: [Follow the editor theme #6](https://github.com/sunmorgus/vscode-json-editor/issues/6). [The extension project might be dead](https://github.com/sunmorgus/vscode-json-editor/issues/20), so [another user forked it and made some of the requested changes](https://github.com/sunmorgus/vscode-json-editor/issues/6#issuecomment-637576297), which they published as the [`GregChamblin.vscode-json-editor`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GregChamblin.vscode-json-editor) extension <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the above info by googling "`github vscode json editor issues dark theme`".